# My data gets null when app is relaunched after being at background for some time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, android-livedata

I am using retrofit to fetch some data from api and using Live data to observe the change in data but whenever I press the home button and start using different apps and after sometime when I reopen my app, data gets null and on pressing back it goes to previous fragment where also it needs to fetch data from api but it doesn't fetch that also but when I press back button again it goes to home page and it fetches the data . I don't know why this is happening and what can be its solution.

Comment: You should pay attention that, in the worst case, any App/Activity/Service could be killed from the System expecially if it's in background...so returning to a "background App" could requires a complete re-initialization.

LiveDatas lives until the Activity is destroyed, so if the System has killed your Activity then its LiveDatas were also killed/freed.

How to manage this depends of HOW your App is build, how your Fragments manages their onStop/onPause/onStart/onResume events and HOW you use LiveData values.....

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid this issue entirely by storing your values using **SharedPreferences** inside the `onPause` and `onDestroy` method overrides.
This way, data will still prevail even if user accidentally clears all running apps.
This will provide data retention stability to your app.